# How to enable hyper-threading and turbo-boost for this processor?

Tags: cpu, hyper-threading, turbo-boost

I bought EliteBook 8740w laptop yesterday. Hyper-threading is not working on windows although I enabled it from BIOS. I have windows 10. Also, when I stress the CPU using CPU-Z program, it doesn't go up to 2.8 GHz as stated on Intel's website. It just goes to 1.7 GHz. During normal work, sometimes it goes up to 2.4 GHz but this is rare and not most of the time. How can I enable Hyper-threading and uses the maximum of turbo-boost feature.

**Solution:**

After enabling Hyperthreading from bios, you need to do some extra steps in bios options too that are related to security. For me, it doesn't make sense that security is related to the Hyperthreading feature. However, here are the steps: System Configuration > Set security level > Intel (R)  HT technology > choose **view**.
[image]

Comment: It's a 1st gen Core CPU, it won't boost up to 2.8 at full load. 1st gen chips could reach boost frequencies only when a single core is under load.

Comment: @gronostaj Okay, thank you. How about the hyper-threading?

Comment: What is your motherboard? Could you add a screenshot of the pertinent BIOS page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Intel specs for the processor of
[Intel Core i7-720QM Processor 6M Cache, 1.60 GHz](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/43122/intel-core-i7-720qm-processor-6m-cache-1-60-ghz.html)
do mention these capabilities, but with a side-note:

---

[image]

---

The side-note adds a lot of conditions that are required to really function:

> ‡ This feature may not be available on all computing systems. Please check with the system vendor to determine if your system delivers this feature, or reference the system specifications (motherboard, processor, chipset, power supply, HDD, graphics controller, memory, BIOS, drivers, virtual machine monitor-VMM, platform software, and/or operating system) for feature compatibility. Functionality, performance, and other benefits of this feature may vary depending on system configuration.

The computer dates from 10 years ago and the CPU is one year older.
The BIOS may be newer and so it had these options available for you to enable,
but turning them on has no effect.
HP has no downloads any more for this computer and especially no newer BIOS.

The conclusion is that the BIOS is trying to turn on the capabilities
that you desire, but they are blocked by one or more other components,
most likely the motherboard.

There is nothing else that you can do except enable them in the BIOS.
Anything more would requires upgrading hardware components such as the motherboard,
which frankly is not feasible for such an old computer.

I'm afraid that the conclusion is negative: You have done all that you could
and it doesn't work. You can do no more.

There is the faint possibility that these capabilities worked with the
original Windows version that came with the computer, that Windows 10
does not support well this hardware, but this is somewhat unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

Here HT was working until last week. Now Windows 10 disable it.
It shows all the 8 cores in a Linux boot.

Edit: It´s an intel core i5 10210u

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1133460)